# Three20 framework replacement

Tags: objective-c, ios, three20

It was awhile since three20 was updated and their ipad support is a little buggy. i'm considering switching to a different framework or use the standard UIKit again. Their lead developer from facebook had started writing his own framework (https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus) and it will probably take him awhile to copy everything.

I'm looking for a similar iOS framework to work with. Any suggestions? I really like the TTNavigator URLs logic and the TTTable data sources instead of the UITableViewDelegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nimbus is an iOS framework whose feature set grows only as fast as its documentation. By focusing on documentation first and features second, Nimbus hopes to be a framework that accelerates the development process of any application by being easy to use and simple to understand.

http://jverkoey.github.com/nimbus/index.html

Answer (score 0):

How about learning the native frameworks?

Comment: Three20 provides alot of ui elements and classes that are missing from the native frameworks.